# Most scalable LWM2M server implementation

Tags: lwm2m

What is the most scalable (considering the number of IoT devices managed) server side implementation of the OMA LWM2M protocol? Which language is it using?

We can use [Eclipse Leshan](https://www.eclipse.org/leshan/) as a benchmark, which is written in Java.

To be more concrete, consider the following scenario: I'm interested in managing fleets of constrained IoT devices. The fleet can vary of many order of magnitudes (1000 to 100000) and ideally I would like the server to be equally responsive. Also (I'm not sure if this is an issue) I would like to server to run with the smallest possible computational resources (as the server could run on the cloud that need to be paid per computation).

Comment: Hi Rexcircus, that is not really a question SE can answer well. For starters the best you can aim for is "largest publicly known" implementation. Still that would not really help with the question of scalability. How well any implementation scales is a dependent from many factors of wich *language* is not necessarily one of the deciding ones.

Comment: Can you add any restrictions or other information that make this a more specific problem?

Comment: Performance testing of any solution is a vast undertaking and depends on MANY factors. There are entire companies built on that, including us. For starters, see this discussion https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/06/testing-iot-platform-resilience-with.html

Comment: I understand that is difficult to answer this, but perhaps there may be someone that has at least tested the different platforms for a given scenario. That would be already pretty useful

Comment: Machnation sells their MIT-E report https://www.machnation.com/product/mit-e-complete/ . We are not affiliated with them, just know of them.